# Mongo ISODate - how to check if 30 or more days passed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Struggling with creating a condition to check if 30 days have passed since specified `ISODate` in mongo.

The field name is `creationDate`, Im using `find` function, and I want to find only these, where 30 days have passed from creation date.

```
User.find({ 
   creationDate: {
      $gte: ...
   }
});
```

In Javascript I would simply do something like

```
(+new Date() - +new Date(creationDate))/60/60/24 >= 30
```

**In a brief**, I want to find only these elements, where `30` days have passed from creating it in mongo db. Looking for any kind of help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just need calculate the 30 days before current time, and use it as the condition as follows:

```js
let fromDate = new Date(Date.now() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 1000);
User.find({
  creationDate: {
    $gte: fromDate
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice. But it doesnt matter that `new Date` is `Date` object and mongodb uses `ISODate` object?

Comment: @Patrickkx ISODate() is a helper function that's built into to MongoDB and wraps the native JavaScript Date object. When you use the ISODate() constructor from the Mongo shell, it actually returns a JavaScript Date object. please check https://www.compose.com/articles/understanding-dates-in-compose-mongodb/

Comment: Conversion is wrong. Add additional `* 60` for correct result. `new Date(Date.now() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 1000);`

Comment: @HasanSefaOzalp you are right, just correct it, thanks.

Comment: I think it can be achieved more readable like this: 

`new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() -1)`

Answer (score 2):

Dates are a tricky topic, so I suggest you to use a dedicated library in order to avoid problems with them.

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/):

```
const aMonthAgo = moment().subtract(30, 'days').toDate();
```

Then change your query to:

```
$lte: aMonthAgo
```

In this way you'll find only documents with a creation date lower than "a month ago".

The [toDate() function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) is needed to get the native Date object from momentjs date type.

Answer (score 0):

As per your need and for the date-related operations, I would suggest using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org) library. You can simply write the query as

```
var subDays = require('date-fns/sub_days')
var olderDate = subDays(new Date(2019, 28, 3), 30)

await User.find({ 
   creationDate: {
      $gte: olderDate
   }
});
```

For the function, you can take a look into [date-fns/sub_days](https://date-fns.org/v1.28.5/docs/subDays).